# Loading types in ocaml from other file

Tags: file, types, module, ocaml

I'm trying to use types that I have in another file (tokenTypes.ml):

```
type token =
| OpenBrace
| CloseBrace
| OpenParen
| CloseParen
| Semicolon
| IntKeyword
| ReturnKeyword
| Negation
| BitwiseComp
| LogicNegation
| Int of int
| Id of string
```

And I'm trying to use it in another file (lexer), the first case worked fine:

```
let token_to_string t =
match t with
| OpenBrace -> "{ "
| CloseBrace -> "} "
| OpenParen -> "( "
| CloseParen -> ") "
| Semicolon -> "; "
| IntKeyword -> "INT "
| ReturnKeyword -> "RETURN "
| Negation -> "-"
| BitwiseComp -> "~"
| LogicNegation -> "!"
| Int i -> Printf.sprintf "INT<%d> " i
| Id id -> Printf.sprintf "ID<%s> " id
```

I can use every token type defined, but then when I'm trying to create a new instance of the type token the compiler says:

> The constructor Negation does not belong to type TokenTypes.token

so I have to create a module with ocamlopt -c tokenTypes.ml and then use it in the code with open, like this:

```
lex_rest char_list = 
let open TokenTypes in
match char_list with
    | [] -> []
    | '{'::rest -> OpenBrace::(lex_rest rest)
    | '}'::rest -> CloseBrace::(lex_rest rest)
    | '('::rest -> OpenParen::(lex_rest rest)
    | ')'::rest -> CloseParen::(lex_rest rest)
    | ';'::rest -> Semicolon::(lex_rest rest)
    | '-'::rest -> Negation::(lex_rest rest)
    | '~'::rest -> BitwiseComp::(lex_rest rest)
    | '!'::rest -> LogicNegation::(lex_rest rest)
```

is there a way to not use the module? I want to quit the open part and only use the source code, not the module.

Help pls :c

Comment: It seems like you're asking for some kind of textual inclusion facility, similar (say) to the C preprocessor's `#include` directive. OCaml doesn't really have anything like that. But why are you trying to avoid using a module? That's what they're for.

Comment: Because in the generator phase i use in every function the AST:
[link](https://ibb.co/BqnT0gx)

Comment: I don't really follow. Maybe you're saying that it becomes cumbersome to open the module in all your functions? You can say `open TokenTypes` once at the top of your .ml file. You don't have to open it in every individual function.

Comment: Yeah, it works, thanks :D, but I want to use only the source code not modules, looks a little strange that i can use the file to match types but not to create Instances of that type

Comment: There's no "soucre code" inclusion in OCaml, so your lexer file must have something in it that you're not showing.

Comment: so #use "lexer.ml" is not an inclusion? I put that in the console and I can use the file functions, you are right, use modules is easier when you try to compile with ocamlc

Comment: There is an include facility in toplevel, yes. But not for the compiler. This is starting to make sense finally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OCaml toplevel (and utop) have a facility for including a file:

```
$ cat m.ml
type abc = A | B | C
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.06.1

# #use "m.ml";;
type abc = A | B | C
# let x = A;;
val x : abc = A
#
```

However, this is just a feature of the toplevel and utop. It's not a feature of the OCaml language:

```
$ cat c.ml
#use "m.ml"

let x = A
$
$ ocamlopt -c c.ml
File "c.ml", line 1, characters 0-1:
Error: Syntax error
```

You need to use a module to do what you want. Modules really are great when you get used to them :-)